# OSX get current mouse state

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm a beginner for Mac development and I'm wondering if there is any private API to judge what state the mouse is,like dragging,left/right mouse down etc.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the instantaneous state, you can use `+[NSEvent mouseLocation]` and `+[NSEvent pressedMouseButtons]`. However, examining the instantaneous state is rarely the right thing to do. If you explain what you're trying to achieve we may be able to suggest better approaches.

Comment: I am trying to do something interesting according to the mouse's current state,for example, I want to get call back if current state changed.

Comment: by the way,this maybe not related to the topic,but do you have any idea on how to simulate touchpad gestures programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a private api. [NSEvent has the method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:)

```
+ (id)addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSEventMask)mask handler:(void (^)(NSEvent*))block
```

which allows monitoring different types of mouse/key events.